# Create a Java REST Application JAR without using Gradle/Maven?

Tags: java, gradle, jar, compilation, javac

Using `Gradle` I know the way to create a `fat jar` that is ran in `Spring Boot` embedded `Tomcat` Server is:

```
1. Gradle clean build bootRun
```

I am wondering though how to create a `fat jar` manually using only `command line` in order to create and run the same exact same jar as above?

I know to create an run a very simple `java` application it is:

```
javac myApp.java
java myApp
```

But how to create a `fat jar` that contains all the projects *dependencies* and then run it? Without using a tool like `gradle` or `maven`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you could just jar up your class(es) with a manifest that specifies where main() is.  For a classic "Hello World" class named Hello, the manifest would look like this...

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: Hello
Class-Path: .
```

You would build it like this...

```
$ jar cvmf MANIFEST.MF Hello.jar Hello.class 
added manifest
adding: Hello.class(in = 415) (out= 285)(deflated 31%)
```

and execute it like this...

```
$ java -jar Hello.jar
Hello World
```

You could do the same with a more complex app with jar dependencies (including an embedded Tomcat), but you would need to unzip all the dependent jars into a directory, and include that in the jar.  A build tool, like Gradle, can make that easier.